# C# WPF MVVM Changes in TextBox is not reflected in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have a ListBox that shows a collection of Person objects with their full name.
I also have 4 TextBoxes that shows all info (FirstName, LastName, Age, Phone) from a Person object  when I click on a Person in the Listbox. This works fine.

I can change the values in the TextBoxes and they will be saved in the TexBoxes but it is not updating the name in the ListBox.

Iv´e tried to change the Binding property in Label Content From FullName to SelectedPerson.FullName but the Path for Label Content is PersonViewModel.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding PersonCollectionVM}"
               SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"
               Grid.Row="0">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Label Content="{Binding FullName}" />
            </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      </ListBox>




<Grid Grid.Column="2">
      <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedPerson.FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

```
public class MainViewModel
    {
        private PersonRepository _personRepo;
        private List<PersonViewModel> _personCollectionVM;
 
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            _personRepo = new PersonRepository();
            _personCollectionVM = new List<PersonViewModel>();
 
            foreach (Person person in _personRepo.GetAll())
            {
                _personCollectionVM.Add(new PersonViewModel(person));
            }
        }
 
        public List<PersonViewModel> PersonCollectionVM => _personCollectionVM;
 
        public PersonViewModel SelectedPerson { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class PersonViewModel
    {
        private Person _person;
 
        public PersonViewModel(Person person)
        {
            _person = person;
        }
        public string FirstName
        {
            get => _person.FirstName; 
            set => _person.FirstName = value;
        }
 
        public string LastName
        {
            get => _person.LastName; 
            set=> _person.FirstName = value;
        }
 
        public int Age
        {
            get => _person.Age;
            set => _person.Age = value;
        }
 
        public string Phone
        {
            get => _person.Phone;
            set => _person.Phone = value;
        }
 
        public string FullName => _person.FirstName + " " + _person.LastName;     
        
    }
```

Comment: Your ViewModel must implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raise the propertyChanged event whenever a property value changed

Comment: I´m not all there with INotifyPropertyChanged yet in this project. It should be solvable without the Interface

Comment: No. This is how the UI gets notified that something changed and can update the display. Without it you get no update.